# Is it possible to have a dynamic cover page?

Tags: php, html, wkhtmltopdf

On my Drupal 8 website I am using Entity Print(phpwkhtmltopdf) to generate a pdf from html. On the platform we have the same content in several languages and depending on the language I need to add different cover pages to the file.

Currently it is done like following, and it is the same cover page for all languages.

```
$this->pdf->addCover('../modules/entity_print/files/cover_page.html');
```

Is it possible to have a dynamic cover page for the pdf?

EDIT: 
The generation of pdf file implies three steps. 1st a user selects a language (dropdown menu), 2d the user selects chapters for downloading (select list), and on the 3d step the user presses the "Download" button.

When the user selects the language the form's action gets changed, we append the language code, so that the right translation of the content is fetched. When the user presses the button to "Download", then the wkhtltopdf engine gets called. And on this step I would need to pass the langcode to the engine to add the appropriate cover page for the pdf.

I can add a Cover Page with options:

```
$pdf->addCover($page, $pageOptions);
```

Under $pageOptions I can pass the langcode. But how can I pass langcode to the PrintEngine?

Comment: `$this->pdf->addCover($appropriate_page_for_language)`, where `$appropriate_page_for_language` is the file you want to add, should work. Or are you asking how to construct `$appropriate_page_for_language` itself?

Comment: I am searchhing for a way how to pass phpwkhtmltopdf the langcode. See the "EDIT" note, please